# Error: column "undefined" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express

Hy everyone

I'm a new developer ReactJS. I tried to set up Firebase into my backend and I've a problem with my frontend. If I'm running my API using a postman, my API work and send a message from my backend but if I running my code from frontend I got error like this **Column in the table is users and is not undefined**

```
 { error: column "undefined" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (C:\fordg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:567:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\fordg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:391:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\fordg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
  name: 'error',
  length: 109,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42703',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '55',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '3183',
  routine: 'errorMissingColumn' }
```

and this is my backend code

```
Orders.patch([ Object.assign({id: req.params.id}, req.body) ])
    .then(orders => {
        DB.query("SELECT oauth FROM users WHERE id = "+req.body.driver+" OR id = "+req.body.customer+"").then(res=>{
            res.map((row,i)=>{
                let tmp = {
                    token: row.oauth.token
                }

                res[i] = tmp;
            });

            // console.log(res);
            const arrayToken = res.map(function (obj) {
                return obj.token;
            });

            // console.log(arrayToken);

            const message = { 
            // to: res[0].token,
            registration_ids: arrayToken,
          notification: {
            body: "Hey! you got update order notification."
          }
        };

        fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
          console.log(response);
        })
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        jsonData = util.jsonData(null, orders);
        res.json(jsonData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        jsonData = util.jsonData(400);
        res.status(jsonData.code).json(jsonData);
    })
})
```

So how to fixed it and can you help me explain error of my code ?

Comment: (1) Why are you using string concatenation to build your SQL? Don't you think placeholders would be a better idea? (2) What's in `req.body.driver` and `req.body.customer`? I'm pretty sure at least one of them is `undefined`.

Comment: Value of `req.body.driver` and `req.body.customer` is id

Comment: I suggest find a better way to build your query, this code looks vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: Are you sure about that? You're sending `id = undefined` into the database, ergo one of those two values is `undefined`.

Comment: Ohh ya thank you, one of id is undefined @muistooshort

Comment: There is an issue with postgres here I think. If you query on an non-existent column name (undefined or anything else) it throws an error that should be caught. I'd expect pg to throw so my .catch() function can handle it or to do something internally to not catch the error and not trigger an "unhandled promise rejection" internally.

Answer (score 0):

Error is here

> WHERE id = "+req.body.driver+" OR id = "+req.body.customer+"

You need to use defined variables in this scope